# Laravel : Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: YES) after removing credentials from .env file

Tags: laravel-5, database-connection

I have installed Laravel 6.0 and set up the database. Initially, it was working fine when I have put the database credentials in **.env** file but after removing it from .env file and setting up it in database.php file, I am getting this error.

**Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: YES)**

What is wrong I am doing here?

**Part of my database.php file**

```php
'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'larainfo'),
'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'uname'),
'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'password'),
```

Thanks
J

Comment: Can you show us your `database.php` setup? Without disclosing any credentials

Comment: 'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'larainfo'),
'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'uname'),
'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'password'),

Comment: So the `env()` function retrieves data from your `.env` file. The first parameter is the key the value should be stored at. the second parameter is a fallback value. If you remove your .env file but still use this function it wont work. either put the `.env` file back with the correct values. or use them in your `database.php` file. i recommend the first option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's because you are still taking the configuration in  `.env` file

just remove the `env()` function and the param, so your cofig will like this :

```
'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
'database' => 'larainfo',
'username' => 'uname',
'password' => 'password',
```

i not recommend you to do this,
better set the configuration back as default, and let it retrieve data from env